# org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

I have a schema in that i have 3 tables.Suppose A,B,C.
A is the parent table of child.and B,C are child table.

When I call **hibernateSession.saveOrUpdate** It is **Updating all** three tables.

But in child table I don't have data for parent table but in parent table I have data.So it give Exception

```
 org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned
unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1.
```

So I want to know  Is there any Way in hibernate so that if child table has no data then it inserted else updated while updating parent table data.

**EDIT 1 :**

The query printed like this

```
Update A set name =? where aid = ?
Update B set adder =? where bid = ?
Update C set city =? where cid = ?
```

But I don't have record in B and C table.

**EDIT:2**

So if table B and C has no data then insert data.

Here is my code.

```
A a = session.get(aid);
B b = a.getb();
C c = a.getc();
// Save B if not exists in database
if (b != null) {
    if (b.bid() != null) {

        if (session.get(b.bid()) == null) {
            System.out.println("--record is there in db---");
            session.save(b);
        }
    }
}

// Save C if not exists in database
if (c != null) {
    if (c.cid() != null) {

        if (session.get(c.cid()) == null) {
            System.out
                    .println("--record is there in db in update---");
                session.save(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this exception.

```
Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to turn on hibernate statement logging in your `Hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration to know what is happening as you don't post the table structures and the query.

To enable Hibernate statement logging:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Then please update your question with the query printed.

## Edit 1:

This exception raise when updating an object that have an id which not exist in the table. The error means it was unable to found record with your given id.

#### To avoid this:

You should read the record with the same id:

If it founds a record back then call `update`

Otherwise throw it and show a error like

> Exception record not found.

## Edit 2

Concerning this error:

> Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

You should tell the hibernate session to merge your modified object with the one in the session

```
session.merge(object)
```

Comment: For that i need to insert first and then update.Not showing any error

Comment: after using merge getting exception.[AssertionFailure] an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session) org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can set **show_sql = true** in your hibernate configuration.
Then you can see the update statement which throws exception.
It is not enough to say somethin without seeing your data types,
tables and relations.